# Deleting *.cpp file after compiling with wrong flag order?

Tags: c++, makefile

I really need your help on this one!
I had a problem with my makefile. The error was very common:

```
makefile:11: recipe for target 'exec' failed
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
CC = g++
PY = python
FLAGS = -std=c++11 -O3

all: main exec data

main: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<

exec: main
    time ./$<

data: plot.py main
    $(PY) $<
```

As far as im concerned there is no mistake but I still got the error, maybe main.cpp was not compiled?
Anyway I then tried (out of curiosity):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o main.cpp main
```

And then I got this error:

```
main: In function `_start':
(.text+0x1360): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
main: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
main:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
main: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
main:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
main: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
main:(.data+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in main(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And now my main.cpp is gone. What the actual.. How can I recover it? I have an older version of it because I'm using git, but its rather unfinished and I really need this version.

Comment: "As far as im concerned there is no mistake" -- ah, the magic words.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but you destroyed/overwrote it with `-o main.cpp`. If you don't have a backup of some kind I doubt you can get it back.

Comment: but there is no file main.cpp in my directory. shouldnt there atleast be the overwritten file?

Comment: @vl_stackoverflow As stated in the answers below you may save the file again if you still have it open in an editor (the cached version). The main.cpp was deleted because your build failed when you tried to compile the previous executable.

Comment: thank you all. very helpful information in here. one last thing: why do I get downvoted on this question? I would like to know for future questions, how to "ask properly"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The error was very common

That's the make error. What did it show before that? Did it run the compiler at all? Was there a compile error? What was it?

I addressed your proximate problem below, but the original issue is the compile error. You're fixating on the fact that a build target failed, rather than on understanding *why* it failed.

Builds fail all the time: very commonly because there's a mistake in the code, and very rarely because of an error in a previously-working makefile. As a consequence, you usually want to worry about understanding and fixing the compiler error, before you start changing your makefile or running the compiler manually.

---

> And now my main.cpp is gone. What the actual..

Well, in

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o main.cpp main
```

the option `-o filename` tells g++ to use *filename* for *output*. So, it opened `main.cpp` for output and clobbered the contents.

You meant

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o main main.cpp
```

It's an easy mistake to make, which is why we have build systems to do this stuff for us. And backups. And version control.

In future, you can just type `make main` to select a single target, and make *should* tell you what it's doing.

> How can I recover it?

From your editor, or version control, or backup, or filesystem-level snapshotting if you have a fancy SAN or, in extremis, from memory.

Nothing teaches good source control and backup habits like having to rewrite something from scratch.

---

> there is no main.cpp file anymore. why exactly is that?

When the build failed, the incomplete output file was deleted.

Consider, for reference, how make works. You have a target called `main`, so it checks whether a file called `main` exists.

- if `main` exists, it looks at the dependencies, and sees if any of those files are newer then `main`
- if it thinks main should be (re-)generated (either it doesn't exist or is older than a dependency), it runs the rule you gave it

Now if g++ left an empty (or incomplete) version of `main` lying around after a failed compilation, how would make know to re-generate it the next time you built?

It's essential that the output file be deleted when compilation fails, because otherwise make wouldn't work correctly. You'd also have a directory full of empty or corrupt partly-compiled executables and object files, which doesn't sound like such a great idea.

---

In other news, your `exec` target doesn't create a file called `exec`. This should be a `.PHONY` rule. So, probably, should `data`.

Comment: 1. there is no main.cpp file anymore. why exactly is that?
2. so is this $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $< $@ correct? because it didn't work when I compiled my program before
3. I have a backup, but still I need to rewrite some code...

Comment: 1. because g++ deletes the output file if compilation fails, rather than leave corrupt partial executable files around. 2. the makefile rule looks fine

Comment: Oh, and - the _important_ error, which you haven't shown, is the _compiler_ error. That's what you need to understand, and to fix.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o main.cpp main
```

Where you specify that the output should be placed in `main.cpp`. You try to compile `main` and store the result in `main.cpp`. Since the compile failed, the output file is removed after compilation stopped. So no `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: Just save the file again in your editor.

To do so, press C-x C-w and type the filename again.

Comment: out of curiosity: how this answers the question?

Comment: @BЈовић Question by OP: "How can I recover it?"